# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined, but I have bound the method and it is not undefined in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

After looking at similar questions people have asked here, I found that people ran into typos or forgot to bind the method in their constructor. However, I haven't found any typos and when I console.log the method I am trying to bind in the constructor it is not undefined, it in fact returns just the function I am looking to bind.

In my component I am creating a toggle edit button that when a user clicks on 'edit' they will first encounter a modal that will guide them through steps for security verification. This method updates the state, in particular one prop called 'shown' and when it is updated that shown prop is passed down to another component (for the modal) that will pop up when shown is set to true. If the user passes the security barriers, then editMode is set to true, which will open up fields that can be edited and then shown will be set to false since there is no need for the modal after passing the security steps. Like I said before, I cannot figure out why it is telling me that toggleEditMode is undefined because when logging it in the constructor it does not return undefined.

I've tried changing it to 
`this.toggleEditMode = toggleEditMode.bind(this)`
but like I expected that did not work either.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Name from '../../Common/FormFields/Name';
import BusinessAddress from '../../Common/FormFields/BusinessAddress';
import PhoneNumber from '../../Common/FormFields/PhoneNumber';
import EditModal from ‘../../EditModal';
import EditingToggleButton from '../../Common/EditingToggleButton';

class BusinessInformation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState(props);

    console.log(‘toggleEditMode’, this.toggleEditMode)
    //this returns the function I have below and not undefined in the console
    this.toggleEditMode = this.toggleEditMode.bind(this);
    this.cancelEdit = this.cancelEdit.bind(this);
    this.authHandler = this.authHandler.bind(this);
  }


  getInitialState(props) {
    return {
      editMode: false,
      shown: false,
      form: {
        phone: {
          value: “555-555-5555”,
          valid: true,
        },
        address: {
          value: “123 Main St”,
          valid: true,
        },
        city: {
          value: “Springfield”,
          valid: true,
        },
        state: {
          value: “RI”,
          valid: true,
        },
        zip: {
          value: “11111”,
          valid: true,
        },
      },
    };
  }

  toggleEditMode() {
    this.setState({editMode: true, shown: true})
  }

  authHandler(response) {
    switch(response.status) {
      case 0:
        console.log('no auth needed', response)
        this.setState({ editMode: true, shown: false });
      case 1:
        console.log('passed all verifications’, response)
        this.setState({ editMode: true, shown: false });
      case 100: 
        console.log(‘there was an error, inspect response.errorCode’)
        this.setState({ editMode: false, shown: false });
      case 101:
        console.log('interrupted by user’)
        this.setState({ editMode: false, shown: false });
    }
  }

  cancelEdit() {
    this.setState(this.getInitialState(this.props));
  }

  render() {
    const {
      editMode,
      shown,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="pad-4-l-md-up">
          <div className="row pad-4-b">
          <div className="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
          <EditModal
             onClose={onClose}
             authHandler={authHandler}
             shown={shown}
       />
            <Name
              width="col-md-5 col-xs-4"
            />
            <PhoneNumber
              editMode={editMode}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              labelWidth="col-md-5 col-xs-4"
              inputWidth="col-md-6 col-xs-8"
            />
            <BusinessAddress
              editMode={editMode}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              labelWidth="col-md-5 col-xs-4"
              inputWidth="col-md-6 col-xs-8"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <EditingToggleButton
              editMode={editMode}
              toggleEditMode={this.toggleEditMode}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BusinessInformation;
```

The component for EditingToggleButton looks as follows:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const EditingToggleButton = ({ editMode, toggleEditMode }) => (
  (editMode) ? ''
   : (
    <Fragment>
      <a
        id="editingToggleButton"
        className="display-block text-align-center-sm-down"
        role="button"
        href="javascript:void(0);"
        onClick={toggleEditMode}
        onKeyDown={toggleEditMode}
      >
        <span className="icon icon-sm dls-icon-edit" />
      </a>
    </Fragment>
  )
);

export default EditingToggleButton;
```

When trying to render everything in the browser I am met with the error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`
specifically referring to toggleEditMode in sources within google chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `ES6` way of binding `handler functions` ?

For example:

```
toggleEditMode = () => {
this.setState({editMode: true, shown: true})
```

}

and later

```
<EditingToggleButton
          editMode={editMode}
          toggleEditMode={()=>this.toggleEditMode()}
        />
```

Comment: So unfortunately I just tried that and it still has resulted in the same error :/ Thank you though

Comment: Can you put your code snippet in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). So that I can have a look at the issue closely.